# Implement database JPA and JPA client class in different bundles (Apache Karaf and OpenJPA)

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, apache-karaf

I have installed Karaf and OpenJPA and tested it, as was mentioned [here](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access). I installed the [examplejpa](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/db/examplejpa), it works fine without any error.
But, I need to use this jpa (Person class and PersonService interface) in another Karaf bundle.
In the other word, I have installed examplejpa. Now I want to create new bundle which gets access to the database through examplejpa bundle.
How can I do this matter?

Generally, is there any way to implement database JPA and JPA client class in different bundles?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to expose a service from your examplejpa project and access this service from your new bundle.

In the blueprint, of the examplejpa project, the service "personService" is declared:

```
<service ref="personService" interface="net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.PersonService" />
```

You can reuse this service in an other bundle by making a reference to it:

```
<reference id="rpersonService" interface="net.lr.tutorial.karaf.db.examplejpa.PersonService" />
```

After that you can inject that reference to a variable of a class:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.new.package.MyClasses">
    <property name="myPersonService" ref="rpersonService" />
</bean>
```

Do not forget to had a dependency in your pom to this project and to import the proper packages.